# Emulating range-for syntax before C++11

Tags: c++, foreach, c++98

I have range-for loops in code that now must be compatible with versions older than C++11.
Is there some way to emulate that syntax—to define it somehow at the head of the file in C++98?

I tried to use a macro, but their parentheses and commas don’t seem to be compatible with

```cpp
for (Node* a : mylist) {
    cout << *a << endl;
}
```

Comment: `BOOST_FOREACH` might be an adequate replacement but I believe even that requires C++03. If I was tasked with that I would just bite the bullet and fix them, one at a time.

Comment: If there were a painless transparent way to implement the "for each" loop in older c++ versions, it would be implemented that way. Instead a piece of new syntax was introduced so probably there isn't a clean way to do that.

Comment: Thanks! @jakub_d you're probably right, I'll give it up (so much for healthy curiosity).

Comment: First time seeing this construct called a "shadow iterator" :) -- `BOOST_FOREACH` is probably the best thing you'll get.

Comment: @bendboaz A global text replace may suffice if the loop is not too complicated.